# Whois tells me a domain is unregistered. Why are the registrars charging $3,000

Tags: domain-registrar, whois, domain-registration

Whois tells me `tiger.top` is unregistered but NameSilo, Hover and Namecheap all claim that it is a 'premium' domain and want over $3k for its initial registration. What's going on? Why is the price so high?

I imagine it could be one of the following reasons:

- The information from Whois is incorrect.
- The registrars have a price-fixing racket going on.
- The `.top` registry has a list of names it charges extra for.

Why is an apparently unregistered domain name so expensive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9990/35/how-to-get-a-premium-domain/#a) has some good information, specifically point 2.

Essentially, you're seeing a domain marked as premium by the registry - they think it has the potential to be very valuable (memorable, short, popular word/phrase, or something else), so they've decided that it will cost more.

Comment: And if you read between the lines in the link, you kinda get the feeling it's to discourage rampant speculation such as was seen back in the dot-com boom when people were snapping up relatively cheap domains with the sole intention of reselling them at exorbitant prices.

Comment: @BrandonXavier dot-com boom?  Snapping up cheap domains?  Thats a Saturday night for most developers .... now, about all those side projects I got around to buying domains for but not actually doing any coding...

Comment: @Moo LOL! I wish there was space here to tell the story of how a wannabe domain squatter registered domains for all the local car dealerships in the city I was living in back around '97 or '98.  Then offering them up for sale at $5k each.  It didn't work out as planned for the squatter . . .

Answer (score 0):

I exactly encouter this very same issue today for a .com domain with a not-common English word that is currently "unregistered", and registrars are asking for $8,000 USD. It seems like straight price gouging but maybe there is more to this pricing scheme.

Some say that the top level .com registry, which is Verisign is imposing these prices on any domain that hits a list of keywords. Keywords that are considered high quality in terms of marketing value. Verisign is under US juristiction and ICANN. Therefore, it can be considered a government policy

This is perhaps a mechanism to reduce squatters who want to buy and flip a domain name for profit, or developers who aimlessly waste a good domain name. But, the policy also sacrifices geniune tiny startups who want to buy a catchy domain name for legitimate purposes.